# pysftp copying remote directory using get_r()

Tags: python-3.x, sftp, pysftp

I am trying to copy contents of a remote directory to my local directory using pysftp.

Here's the code:

```
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

p=pysftp.Connection("10.2.2.99",username= "user",
                   password="password", cnopts=cnopts)
remote_path = '/cradius-data/files/webapps/vcm/somedirectory'
local_path = 'E:\\New Folder\\FTP Download Folder'
p.get_r(remotedir=remote_path,localdir=local_path)
```

I get the following File Not Found error message,

```
No such file or directory: 'E:\\New Folder\\FTP Download Folder\\./cradius-data/files/webapps/vcm/somedirectory/SOME_File.ZIP'
```

It seems that both the paths are being concatenated for some reason which is leading to an incorrect FileNotFound exception.
Also ,I've verified that the file is present in the remote directory.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: it is because of the '\\' in paths from windows, if you are copying from windows to Linux then this problem occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of the '\\' in path string from windows, if you are copying from windows to Linux then this problem occurs. I had the same problem, I rewrote the path strings removing the extra '\' and everything worked fine, you can use my code, include the DirectoryCopy.py in your script and use it as used in script.py below.

DirectoryCopy.py:

```
import paramiko
import os
import socket
from stat import S_ISDIR

class SSHSession(object):
# Usage:
# Detects DSA or RSA from key_file, either as a string filename or a
# file object.  Password auth is possible, but I will judge you for 
# using it. So:
# ssh=SSHSession('targetserver.com','root',key_file=open('mykey.pem','r'))
# ssh=SSHSession('targetserver.com','root',key_file='/home/me/mykey.pem')
# ssh=SSHSession('targetserver.com','root','mypassword')
# ssh.put('filename','/remote/file/destination/path')
# ssh.put_all('/path/to/local/source/dir','/path/to/remote/destination')
# ssh.get_all('/path/to/remote/source/dir','/path/to/local/destination')
# ssh.command('echo "Command to execute"')

def __init__(self,hostname,username='root',key_file=None,password=None):
    #
    #  Accepts a file-like object (anything with a readlines() function)  
    #  in either dss_key or rsa_key with a private key.  Since I don't 
    #  ever intend to leave a server open to a password auth.
    #
    self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.sock.connect((hostname,22))
    self.t = paramiko.Transport(self.sock)
    self.t.start_client()
    #keys = paramiko.util.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/known_hosts'))
    key = self.t.get_remote_server_key()
    # supposed to check for key in keys, but I don't much care right now to find the right notation
    key_file=None
    if key_file is not None:
        if isinstance(key,str):
            key_file=open(key,'r')
        key_head=key_file.readline()
        key_file.seek(0)
        if 'DSA' in key_head:
            keytype=paramiko.DSSKey
        elif 'RSA' in key_head:
            keytype=paramiko.RSAKey
        else:
            raise Exception("Can't identify key type")
        pkey=keytype.from_private_key(key_file)
        self.t.auth_publickey(username, pkey)
    else:
        if password is not None:
            self.t.auth_password(username,password,fallback=False)
        else: raise Exception('Must supply either key_file or password')
    self.sftp=paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(self.t)

def command(self,cmd):
    #  Breaks the command by lines, sends and receives 
    #  each line and its output separately
    #
    #  Returns the server response text as a string

    chan = self.t.open_session()
    chan.get_pty()
    chan.invoke_shell()
    chan.settimeout(20.0)
    ret=''
    try:
        ret+=chan.recv(1024)
    except:
        chan.send('\n')
        ret+=chan.recv(1024)
    for line in cmd.split('\n'):
        chan.send(line.strip() + '\n')
        ret+=chan.recv(1024)
    return ret

def put(self,localfile,remotefile):
    #  Copy localfile to remotefile, overwriting or creating as needed.
    self.sftp.put(localfile,remotefile)

def put_all(self,localpath,remotepath):
    #  recursively upload a full directory
    os.chdir(os.path.split(localpath)[0])
    parent=os.path.split(localpath)[1]
    #print('Parent dir:',parent)
    for walker in os.walk(parent):
        #print("walker:",walker)
        try:
            #print("Directory created with path:",os.path.join(remotepath,walker[0]) )
            #temp path for directory for changin  all the '\' to '/' 
            direcTemp = os.path.join(remotepath,walker[0])
            direcTemp = direcTemp.replace('\x5c','/')
            #self.sftp.mkdir(os.path.join(remotepath,walker[0]))
            self.sftp.mkdir(direcTemp)

        except:
            pass
        for file in walker[2]:
            #in order to transfer the whole directory it is necesssary to change all the '\' to '/'

            localTemp=os.path.join(walker[0],file)
            localTemp=localTemp.replace('\x5c','/')

            remoTemp =os.path.join(remotepath,walker[0],file)
            remoTemp = remoTemp.replace('\x5c','/')

           # print('Local windows path:',localTemp)
            print('Remo Linux path:',remoTemp)

            #self.put(localTemp,os.path.join(remotepath,walker[0],file))
            self.put(localTemp,remoTemp)

def get(self,remotefile,localfile):
    #  Copy remotefile to localfile, overwriting or creating as needed.
    self.sftp.get(remotefile,localfile)

def sftp_walk(self,remotepath):
    # Kindof a stripped down  version of os.walk, implemented for 
    # sftp.  Tried running it flat without the yields, but it really
    # chokes on big directories.
    path=remotepath
    files=[]
    folders=[]
    for f in self.sftp.listdir_attr(remotepath):
        if S_ISDIR(f.st_mode):
            folders.append(f.filename)
        else:
            files.append(f.filename)
    print (path,folders,files)
    yield path,folders,files
    for folder in folders:
        new_path=os.path.join(remotepath,folder)
        for x in self.sftp_walk(new_path):
            yield x

def get_all(self,remotepath,localpath):
    #  recursively download a full directory
    #  Harder than it sounded at first, since paramiko won't walk
    #
    # For the record, something like this would gennerally be faster:
    # ssh user@host 'tar -cz /source/folder' | tar -xz

    self.sftp.chdir(os.path.split(remotepath)[0])
    parent=os.path.split(remotepath)[1]
    try:
        os.mkdir(localpath)
    except:
        pass
    for walker in self.sftp_walk(parent):
        try:
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(localpath,walker[0]))
        except:
            pass
        for file in walker[2]:
            self.get(os.path.join(walker[0],file),os.path.join(localpath,walker[0],file))
def write_command(self,text,remotefile):
    #  Writes text to remotefile, and makes remotefile executable.
    #  This is perhaps a bit niche, but I was thinking I needed it.
    #  For the record, I was incorrect.
    self.sftp.open(remotefile,'w').write(text)
    self.sftp.chmod(remotefile,755)
```

script.py:

```
import paramiko
from DirectoryCopy import SSHSession

def creat_ssh_connection(host, port, username, password, keyfilepath, keyfiletype):
    ssh = None
    key = None
    try:
        if keyfilepath is not None:
            # Get private key used to authenticate user.
            if keyfiletype == 'DSA':
                # The private key is a DSA type key.
                key = paramiko.DSSKey.from_private_key_file(keyfilepath)
            else:
                # The private key is a RSA type key.
                key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(keyfilepath)

        # Create the SSH client.
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

        # Setting the missing host key policy to AutoAddPolicy will silently add any missing host keys.
        # Using WarningPolicy, a warning message will be logged if the host key is not previously known
        # but all host keys will still be accepted.
        # Finally, RejectPolicy will reject all hosts which key is not previously known.
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

        # Connect to the host.
        if key is not None:
            # Authenticate with a username and a private key located in a file.
            ssh.connect(host, port, username, None, key)
        else:
            # Authenticate with a username and a password.
            ssh.connect(host, port, username, password)    

        #console = ssh.invoke_shell()
        #console.keep_this = ssh
        return ssh
    except:
        print("exception")



ssh=SSHSession('ipaddres','user_name',password='password_string')
#directory_win is copied inside the directory_lin folder.
ssh.put_all('../../windows/example/directory_win','/linux/example/directory_lin/')
```